# How to create a Spring MVC project to validate Login details sent from Android application request in Tomcat Server

Tags: java, android, spring, tomcat

I have created a project in Spring MVC with login form inside the project and validated.

I must create a project only checking the username and password credentials which I'm sending from Android app. I'm finding difficulties in implementing. Someone has tried with it please share with me the links/tutorials.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: As I have login activity in android app. There is no need of view in springs right. I dint get any samples to connect from android app to springs and I'm new to MVC. Any tutorials please share with me.

Comment: https://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/login-application-for-android/. Similar to the link sample I have implemented in servlets. Now I'm trying in Springs.